# Is this a question that would be better suited as a community wiki?

Tags: discussion

Regarding the question: [What are must-read books for DevOps engineer to become a true expert?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/what-are-must-read-books-for-devops-engineer-to-become-a-true-expert)

I see its being down voted, and I can understand why. However, I personally feel like this would be a great starting point for a community wiki answer, much like the 'list of useful memes': [What are known useful and misleading memes in the DevOps culture?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/what-are-known-useful-and-misleading-memes-in-the-devops-culture)

Would it be appropriate to leave this question open, and simply convert the current answer to a wiki so we can all add to it over time?

Comment: I wouldn't put the meme and book list on the same usefulness steps, former is a list of concepts, the second is a library index which will probably fade out with time as the general idea evolves. Add this to the point everyone will have its own appreciation on what books are good or not and you'll end up with edit wars on the list. (I did cast the final close vote btw as the question is absolutely ill defined and really too broad and opinion based)

Comment: Hmmm. I see your logic, though I still feel the same could be said about the memes: relevant more or less to some more than others, and the meaningfulness could fade over time. That being said, I would agree they are different in scale. You're right, the memes would apply to far _more_ people, and be meaningful _far_ longer. 12 factor app is a good example. 7 years later, and its still just as relevant. Not many 7 year old tech books for DevOps could claim the same relevancy.

Comment: You're right. That "computer science analogy" is a really good one. Thanks.